# Auto formatting of excel cells upon exporting

Tags: c#, asp.net

A sort of a newbie here! I just want to know is there a way to auto format the cells in excel, upon exporting it? I am using c#.net and I can't find any codes for what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What are you exporting it from? Are you creating the .xlsx file from scratch?

Comment: No I am not creating the .xlsx file from scratch, I have a winform application. And an "Export to Excel" button. The result is good, but as soon as I open the exported .xlsx file, the excel cells is at its default format. What I wanted is the cells will be auto formatted depending on the data inside each cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to create the excel file from scratch or edit it's xml source directly, consider using the OpenXml SDK here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

If you would like an easier approach use the classes/methods provided in the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel) namespace. Performance here is much worse and you will be required to have Office installed, but the learning curve is not nearly as steep as for OpenXml

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using EEPlus, it has everything you need including auto formatting cells and it's incredibly fast with no need to open Excel.

You can find more info here: [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)